# Python Flask - Add POST data to sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, http, flask, server

I am sending data from a python script to the server using POST, I want to then store that data in an SQLite database. My current code returns a 500 internal server error to the client.

Here is the client script:

```
import requests
from random import randint

def WindSpeed():
    #Creates makeshift WindSpeed data to send to server
    return randint(0,20)


def Temp():
    #Creates makeshift Temp data to send to server
    return randint(0,20)


post_data = {'windspeed':WindSpeed(), 'temp': Temp()}
#POSTs post_data to server
r = requests.post('http://10.0.0.119', data = post_data)
print (r.text)
```

And here is the server script:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, g
import json
import sqlite3 as sql


app = Flask(__name__)

def insert_readings(windspeed):
    DATABASE = '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/weather.db'
    with sql.connect(DATABASE) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather_readings (windspeed) VALUES (?)", (windspeed))
        con.commit()

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        windspeed = request.form['windspeed']       
        insert_readings(windspeed)
        return "Done"
    else:
        insert_readings(4,3) #This works
        return render_template('main.html', name='GET')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It is worth noting that the `insert_readings` function works when called in the `else` statement and in other files. Also, the same error is returned when I tried to write to a text file.
The POST request works on its own when just returning `windspeed` so the i don't think the problem is with getting the data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have only the windspeed key of the dict, just one value.

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        windspeed = request.form['windspeed']       
        insert_readings(windspeed)
        return "Done"
else:
        insert_readings(4,3) #This works
```

and you tried with two values.

Try it:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            value1 = request.form['windspeed']
            value2 = request.form['temp']
            insert_readings(int(value1),int(value2))
            return "Done"
```

Could you post more information about the error?

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. It turns out the main problem was the permissions of the database file, when I ran the script with `sudo`, it worked. But the server did not have the privileges to write to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the client script and the server script looks good by cite. The 500 internal server error is a very broad error message, it is hard to gauge the problem without testing the scripts on your setup. Could you provide the server setup/configuration.